# Changing "Selected" Attribute of a Dropdown-List does not work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown-list in a form, whichs onchange event gets listenend by jquery and leads to an AJAX call. Afterwards Jquery just sets/removes the `selected` attribute depending on the answere of the server:

```
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $("#user_select").on("change", function(){
        var value = $("#user_select").val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "../ajax/change_permission.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { user_id: value }
        }).done(function(data){
            var i = 0;
            while(i < 4){
                $("#perm_"+i).attr("selected", false);
                $("#perm_"+i).removeClass("active_perm");
                i++;
            }
            $("#perm_"+data).attr("selected", true);
            $("#perm_"+data).addClass("active_perm");
        });
    });
});
```

In my `user_select` dropdown are my users whose permission should be shown if I select it.
The form (where the select should be set to) looks like that:

```
<select id="user_permission" class="form-control">
    <option id="perm_0" value="0">Berechtigungsstufe</option>
    <option id="perm_1" value="1">Administrator</option>
    <option id="perm_2" value="2">Super-User</option>
    <option id="perm_3" value="3">User</option>
</select>
```

The problem now is that if a option has already been selected once, it cannot be set to active again, or better said, the selected tag still gets aplied to the option, but it isn't changed anymore (just stays on option zero). After i've selected every option once, the select looks like that:

```
<select id="user_permission" class="form-control">
    <option id="perm_0" value="0">Berechtigungsstufe</option>
    <option id="perm_1" value="1" class="">Administrator</option>
    <option id="perm_2" value="2" class="">Super-User</option>
    <option id="perm_3" value="3" class="">User</option>
</select>
```

The `selected="selected"` attribute still gets applied to the option, but the selected option won't be changed (the display isn't changed) anymore. Already thought it is bugging because of the empty class tag, but it changes nothing if i remove it.

Anyone having an idea what may cause that problem?

EDIT: All in all it is that [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8oy8n59a/) just without the Random values :p

EDIT ANSWERE: The Jquery ".attr" does not work properly in Firefox 42.0. Instead i've used ".prop", what works correctly.

Comment: What is your browser

Comment: Mozilla Firefox 42.0

Comment: It works for me! any way don't use $(".cls").attr("") function for this kind of place. Instead of use $("#perm_"+data).prop("selected", true); Anyway both works for me.

Comment: Add that $("#perm_"+data).prop("selected", true); as the answere, it works properly with it! Thank you!

Comment: Don't you want the 15 Reputations? :p Your answere is correct, i'll accept it if you add it.

Comment: I added the answer not only for reputation but also for future references. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery has two different functions attr() and prop(). Those two use for different purposes. attr is for all attributes. prop is for properties. In your case dropdown element "selected" is not a attribute. It is a property. Therefore you should use prop function as below.

```
$("#perm_"+data).prop("selected", true);
```

Note: However some modern browser works for both, but for cross browser compatibility always try to use correct one.

Comment: There we go. Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to tell you that I checked the difference in Chrome, where it also works properly with attr (shame on me that I forgot to check that out before). Seems like an incompatibility to firefox

Answer (score 1):

Why you use options under select you can directly use `$("#user_permission").val(1)`

Comment: 1. Already this question has been answered. 2. Because that are two dropdown lists where ones selected valuee depending on the what's selected on the other

Comment: With id only one dropdown value will set. You can use class.
ie. $(".form-control").val(1)

Comment: Did you at least read the question? I just want to manipulate one value (attribute) depending on the answere of AJAX.

Comment: It's simple.
$(".form-control option").attr("selected", false) ;
$(".form-control option[value=1]").attr("selected", true) ;

Comment: That is not even close to be an answere, this works even more worse than my way... And this is just a useless comment because I said that there is a probleme with the ".attr" which you could've read above. Also there is no sence to change the targeted attribute to target a class instead of an id, because I already said that it is no targeting problem!